# Nested FHIR Bundles

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

Can I have FHIR Bundle( list of resources) within a FHIR Bundle( list of FHIR Bundles) ?
I'm building a Search API which response should include list of resources and if a resources have multiple related resources, then it should be grouped in the response so the FHIR Client can display it without making any additional API calls

Answer (score 1):

yes a bundle can contain bundles. Note, though, that usually you would just include the extra resources in the bundle directly, since they'll be resolved by URL. Nesting bundles just makes it harder for the client. (see how _include is defined in the spec at http://hl7.org/fhir/search.html#include)

Answer (score 0):

The main use for bundles of bundles is when you want to submit a batch of messages or pass around a bunch of documents.